# Should we prefer singular or plural in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

My experience with English.SE has led me to favor the plural, as the community there opted to use it (see the relevant meta.english post [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/10041)).  However, I thought I'd pose the question to the community.  I've already remapped tags from [bishop](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bishop) to [bishops](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bishops), as well as the rest of the chess pieces, but before going further, I decided to post here.

Vote on the answers below to state your choice.

Comment: There is now both a [tag:novelty] and a [tag:novelties] tag. According to the vote below, [tag:novelties] should be the preferred choice.

Comment: *doubled-pawn* should definitely be changed to *doubled-pawns*

Answer (score 3):

## Plural

Vote this choice up if you want tags referring to countable objects to be generally in the plural ([pawns](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pawns), [openings](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openings), [sacrifices](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacrifices))

Vote it down if you are strongly opposed to the above.

Answer (score 2):

## Singular

Vote this choice up if you want tags referring to countable objects to be generally in the singular ([pawn](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pawn), [opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening), [sacrifice](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sacrifice))

Vote it down if you are strongly opposed to the above.